# Why does django pgm crash when entered number exceeds DecimalField max_digits?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following field in my Django model:

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

and the following code in my form:

```
price = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': '0.01', 'text-align': 'right;'}))
```

(BTW, the text-align doesn't work - different problem, I think)

It works when displayed in a form. In fact, when I try to use more than 2 decimal places, the form pops up a message:

[image]

However, if I enter too many digits, as in:

[image]

Django throws the following error:

> InvalidOperation at /balancer/set_security_prices/2017-10-14
>   []
>
> Request Method:   POST Request
>
> URL:  http://localhost:8000/balancer/set_security_prices/2017-10-14
>
> Django Version:   1.9.1 Exception Type:   InvalidOperation Exception
>
> Value:     [] Exception
>
> Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py
>   in format_number, line 200 Python
>   Executable:   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
>   Python Version:   3.5.1

The is_valid() check I do before saving the data doesn't trap the problem. This doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't Django protect against this or must I add `try ...except` code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first validation error generated by browser, and you should to add validation for max length to the input if you want the same effect
for example:

```
price = forms.DecimalField(
     widget=forms.NumberInput(
         attrs={'step': '0.01', max='999999', 'text-align': 'right;'})
         #                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
)
```

Comment: Works! Although the syntax for the max is 'max': '999999'  Still not sure why Django generated the too many decimals error but not the too many digits error. Seems like it should.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wait, perhaps the 'step' is throwing that to many decimal places error. OK, think I'm good now. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help you.